# Perl Regex: How to remove quotes inside quotes from CSV line

Tags: regex, perl, double-quotes, regex-lookarounds, lookbehind

I've got a line from a CSV file with `"` as field encloser and `,` as field seperator as a string. Sometimes there are `"` in the data that break the field enclosers. I'm looking for a regex to remove these `"`.

My string looks like this:

```
my $csv = qq~"123456","024003","Stuff","","28" stuff with more stuff","2"," 1.99 ","",""~;
```

I've looked at [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) but I don't understand how to tell it to only remove quotes that are

1. not at the beginning of the string
2. not at the end of the string
3. not preceded by a `,`
4. not followed by a `,`

I managed to tell it to remove 3 and 4 at the same time with this line of code:

```
$csv =~ s/(?<!,)"(?!,)//g;
```

However, I cannot fit the `^` and `$` in there since the lookahead and lookbehind both do not like being written as `(?<!(^|,))`.

Is there a way to achieve this only with a regex besides splitting the string up and removing the quote from each element?

Comment: There are two sorts of CSV regexes: those that fail now and those that will fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
$csv =~ s/(?<=[^,])"(?=[^,])//g
```

`1` and `2` implies that there must be at least one character before and after the comma, hence the positive lookarounds. `3` and `4` implies that these characters can be anything but a comma.

Comment: It will also remove a trailing quote. ie. "abc","def" becomes "abc","def. So I added not followed by new line 's/(?<=[^,])"(?=[^,)])(?!$)//g'

Answer (score 10):

For manipulating CSV data I'd reccomend using [Text::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/Text-CSV-1.21/lib/Text/CSV.pm) - there's a lot of potential complexity within CSV data, which while possible to contruct code to handle yourself, isn't worth the effort when there's a tried and tested CPAN module to do it for you

Comment: I know, but I only want to remove the quote, I don't do anything else with the data. This is more of a general question of how the lookaround works.

Comment: Unless you are treating this purely as a learning exercise for regex, you will at some point get bitten by unexpected formatting (ie not handled by your regex) in CSV data.  I ignored this advice myself and learnt the hard way!

Answer (score 4):

Don't use *Regex* for parsing CSV file, CPAN provides lot of good modules like as nickifat suggest, use [Text::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/Text-CSV-1.21/lib/Text/CSV.pm) or you can use [Text::ParseWords](http://perldoc.perl.org/Text/ParseWords.html) like

```
use Text::ParseWords;  
while (<DATA>) {
chomp;     
my @f = quotewords ',', 0, $_;     
print join "|" => @f; 
}  

__DATA__ 
"123456","024003","Stuff","",""28" stuff with more stuff","2"," 1.99 ","",""
```

Output:

```
123456|024003|Stuff||28 stuff with more stuff|2| 1.99 ||
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. I didn't know about `Text::ParseWords` and it looks helpful. But again, I do not intend to use the data from the CSV file. I only wanted to remove quotes inside of the text. I'm neither building the CSV nor reading from it. I'm merely clearing up data that already looks like a CSV file and goes someplace else.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help here. I was having issues with badly formatted CSV with embedded double-quotes. I would make one slight addition to the lookahead portion of the regex otherwise null values at the end of the line will be corrupted:

```
(?<=[^,])\"(?=[^,\n])
```

Adding the \n will eliminate a match against the last double-quote at end-of-line.

Answer (score -1):

the suggested

```
$csv =~ s/(?<=[^,])"(?=[^,])//g;
```

is probably the best answer. Without these advanced regex features, you could also do the same with

```
$csv =~ s/([^,])"([^,])/$1$2/g;
```

or

```
$csv = join (',', map {s/"//g;"\"$_\""} split (',', $csv));
```

I think you should be aware that your string is not well formated csv. In a csv file, double quotes inside values must be doubled (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values). With your format, values cannot contain quotes near commas.

csv is a not so simple format. If you decides to use "real" csv, you should use a module.
Otherwise, you should probably remove all the double quotes in order to simplify your code and clarify that you are not doing csv.

Comment: They're not the same. #2 doesn't handle two quotes in a row. #3 is even worse, splitting fields with commas into two.